# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Vs EC2 Container Service (ECS) - Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Have been running Docker with Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a relatively simple app, and it has been working great. Now with ECS on the horizon, I am interested to know what the differences are between the two services, and why one might use one over the other?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Amazon's [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/faqs/) says the following:

**Q: How is Amazon ECS different from AWS Elastic Beanstalk?**

*AWS Elastic Beanstalk is an application management platform that helps customers easily deploy and scale web applications and services. It keeps the provisioning of building blocks (e.g., EC2, RDS, Elastic Load Balancing, Auto Scaling, CloudWatch), deployment of applications, and health monitoring abstracted from the user so they can just focus on writing code. You simply specify which container images are to be deployed, the CPU and memory requirements, the port mappings, and the container links. Elastic Beanstalk will automatically handle all the details such as provisioning an Amazon ECS cluster, balancing load, auto-scaling, monitoring, and placing your containers across your cluster.
Elastic Beanstalk is ideal if you want to leverage the benefits of containers but just want the simplicity of deploying applications from development to production by uploading a container image. You can work with Amazon ECS directly if you want more fine-grained control for custom application architectures.*

Comment: It would be great, If you list out the fine grained control that we get in ECS, which are not available in beanstalk. This will make it more easier to understand the difference.

Comment: I agree, we need a clear insight of what control you gain with ECS in order to figure out the difference